# what is the matter about this python code?

Tags: python

```
for i in range(30):
    if input() == '-':
        case = 0
    else:
        case = input()
    print(case)
```

here is my code, and result is like this: (emphasized one is input)

```
*-*
0
*10*
*10*
10
```

it works well with printing - for 0, but it prints only every second number if I input numbers in a row

Comment: When you run `case = input()`, that reads a second piece of input.

Comment: What is this *supposed* to do instead, and why?

Answer (score 2):

Each `input()` call is getting you a *new* value. The `input()` that checks for `'-'` returns a different value from the one you assign to `case`. If you want to reuse the same value, you need to assign it to a temporary variable and reuse it, e.g.:

```
for i in range(30):
    inp = input()
    if inp == '-':
        case = 0
    else:
        case = inp
    print(case)
```

With the walrus in 3.8+, you can condense two lines:

```
    inp = input()
    if inp == '-':
```

to one if you really want, but there's little benefit to be had here:

```
    if (inp := input()) == '-':
```

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you call `input()`, it asks for another input from the user.
The correct way to do it is:

```
for i in range(30):
    x = input()
    if x == '-':
        case = 0
    else:
        case = x
    print(case)
```

Comment: This was already suggested in the answer by ShadowRanger before this one was posted.

Comment: Yes, I saw. We wrote it together but he was about 1 min faster